# How to pass result from Model to Controller in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to get data from the database and display it on a webpage using CodeIgniter. I coded my controller, model and view as follows.

Controller;

```
//HomeController

<?php

class HomeController extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('HomeModel');
        $data['records'] = $this->HomeModel->getData();
        $this->load->view('HomeView',$data);

    }
}
?>
```

Model;

```
//HomeModel
<?php

class HomeModel extends CI_Model
{
    public function getData()
    {

          $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM data');
          return $query->unbuffered_row('object');

    }
}
?>
```

View;

```
//HomeView
<?php

echo "Recoeds from database<br>";

while($records)
{
    echo $records->name." ".$records->age."</br>";
}

?>
```

But this code doesn't print anything on the screen.(`echo "Records from database<br>";` )

So I tried the following code given in the CodeIgniter documentation and echoed the result in the model itself rather than return it to the controller and then to the views.It worked fine.

```
//HomeModel
<?php
        class HomeModel extends CI_Model
        {
            public function getData()
            {
                $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM data');
                while ($row = $query->unbuffered_row())
                {
                     echo $row->name;
                     echo $row->age;
                }
             }
        }
?>
```

My question is how do we return the result of the `unbuffered_row()` method into the controller and then to the view as per MVC architecture? We can get the output by echoing result at the model itself but it is against the purpose of the MVC architecture.

Comment: CodeIgniter has nothing to do with MVC architecture.

Comment: you can also use $query->result_array() in the model. Return to controller.there you can easily access data.

Comment: If it doesn't `echo "Records from database<br>";` then check that your HomeView.php file is in the `application/views` folder. Also, what happens if you move your `while(` from the model to the controller and loop through $data['records'] there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `return $query->result();` and then get the right object in the view or controller (that's up to you).

Answer (score 0):

I simulated your code in local.Your mistake is here.$records is object .And your while loop has not  condition for leaving the loop

```
<pre>
    <?php
    var_dump($records);
    echo "Recoeds from database<br>";
    foreach($records as $value) {

        echo $value->name."<br>";

        echo $value->age."<br>";

    }
    ?>
    </pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This One

controller

```
<?php

class HomeController extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('HomeModel');
        $data['records'] = $this->HomeModel->getData();
        $this->load->view('HomeView',$data);

    }
}
?>
```

Model

```
<?php

class HomeModel extends CI_Model
{
    public function getData()
    {

          $data = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM data');
          return array('count'=>$data->num_rows(), 'data'=>$data->result(),'first'=>$data->row());

    }
}
?>
```

View

```
<?php

echo "Recoeds from database<br>";

foreach($record['data'] as $row)
{
    echo $row->name." ".$row->age;
}

?>
```